# Execution order problem when using Action

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core

I have the following C# code running in a console app for .NET Core 2.2 on Debian 9 x64:

```
DbCall(Action action) {
    try {
        lock(thisLock) {
            action();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        //exception handling
    }
}

private T DbCall<T>(Func<T> func) {
    try {
        lock(thisLock) {
            return func();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //exception handling
    }
}

public void RemoveClassAEntity(ClassA classAentity) {
    DbCall(() => {
        DbContext.ClassAEntities.Remove(classAentity);
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
    });
}

public List<ClassA> GetClassAEntities(Func<ClassA, bool> condition) {
    return DbCall(() => {
        return DbContext.ClassAEntities
            .Where(condition)
            .ToList();
    });
}

public void RemoveClassAEntitiesWithCondition() {
    var entities = GetClassAEntities(e => SatisfiesCondition(e));
    entities.Sort();
    entities.ForEach(e => RemoveClassAEntity(e));
}
```

There are multiple methods similar to RemoveClassAEntity, that's why I introduced the DbCall methods, so that I wouldn't need to repeat the lock and exception handling.
The method RemoveClassAEntity is public and can be called from multiple threads. However, it cannot be called from different threads at the same time for the same entity (SatisfiesCondition cannot return true at the same time in different threads)

My problem is that "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entity" error occurs sometimes, originating from the line "action();". I am fairly certain that RemoveClassAEntity is never called with null argument. I couldn't reproduce the issue with a debugger, only by checking error logs in production environment.

I expected the delegate passed to DbCall to be executed synchronously with the calling method, but I get the impression that the delegate is executed after the calling method exits, that's why the exception occurs. If that could be the case, how do I force it to run before the RemoveClassAEntity method exits?
If that's not the case, what could be?

Comment: Did you check the stacktrace of the exception, it could help to narrow the error location. You should use a debugger next

Comment: You are correct that since you are not doing anything that would cause your action to get executed on a separate thread, it will execute synchronously. But according to your description there is some multithreaded stuff going on. We might need to see more. A lot also depends on the details of that `NullReferenceException`. What is null? Those are missing pieces of the puzzle.

Comment: @Kalten I couldn't debug the error since I wasn't able to reproduce it in the development environment, only saw it in production by checking the logs. The stacktrace top is where I mentioned and propagates to the caller of  "RemoveClassAEntity"

Comment: @ScottHannen Thanks for the comment. I didn't write it correctly initially, there is no NullReferenceException, but "Value cannot be null" error, I added more context. If the error isn't somewhere in the code I listed and there is no bug in .NET which could cause the behavior I suspect, it must be in the way I dispatch threads.

Comment: You're iterating over a list and want to delete every entry. Why are you calling SaveChanges(..) for every Remove. It would be better to remove all (RemoveRange) and call it once.
Show us the code where the parameter "entity" exists
Btw.: You should think about to switch to EF async methods, because you're doing I/O stuff.

Comment: @user743414 I also was thinking about optimizing it, but solving the issue and understanding the root cause is more critical for me for now. The parameter entity is in the method Remove of the member DbSet<ClassA> ClassAEntities. DbSet comes from Entity Framework Core (Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite version 2.2.4)

Comment: @RobotShard I've got only one time a error "Value cannot be null" from EF and spend hours of debugging EF-Code just to find that I've a property on a model which wasn't nullable but wasn't set and therby was NULL. So maybethat's your issue too. A missing include when loading or a property forgotten so set correctly.